# GWT - RPC Failure with GAE - Working in local on Greetings sample

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, rpc

I'm encountering a probem with my GWT app. Everything is working great in local but I got Error 500 when the application is deployed on Google App Engine.

To understand the problem, I tried to deploy the sample Web Application example with Greetings service and I still got the same error Remote Procedure Call - Failure.

I think it's coming from my IDE settings but can't figure out what is the problem.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Seems like with the servlet paths .can you show us your web.xml and how you are accessing from browser after deploy ??

Comment: Nothing has been changed on web.xml. I just used the auto-generated Greetings sample in order to test : http://pastebin.com/QRHa6zfz

Comment: You can access the web app at this URL : http://www.urlgone.com/ed095d/

Comment: can you plaste the tomcat log ??

Comment: Sure. Thanks for help. I got the following sequence of Error-Warning-Critical each time I try to call the RPC : http://pastebin.com/iR3CY0zm

Comment: My application is deployed with Google App Engine which is different from Tomcat, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is with `ONLY` servlet paths .

The environment and the folder structure will be cmpletely different in Dev-Mode and Deployment environment .

In The below link ,explained the problem you are facing.

[Eclipse GWT sample greeting project RPC failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623964/eclipse-gwt-sample-greeting-project-rpc-failure) .

Comment: What do you mean by ONLY servlet paths ? The servlet path <url-pattern>/mywebapp/greet</url-pattern> seems to be good as I can reach it (could not complete request but not a 404).

Comment: As the discussion in the  above link are you working on mac ??

Comment: I am not but I don't think it does matter. I work on Eclipse with GWT plugin and App Engine plugin. I deploy the project directly from this plugin.

Comment: Unpack your war and Have you checked that GreentingServiceImpl class is there ?

Comment: Of course it is : I didn't change nothing from the auto generated built in sample code

Comment: OOPs then thats the JDK version problem seems like  .checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712034/app-works-fine-localy-but-it-wont-launch-on-gae

Comment: As I thought, that was an IDE problem. I clean up libraries : installation, paths, build settings and install a proper version of GAE plugin and it now seems to work. Thanks for help.